# JQuery UI selectable - how to disable deselecting elements?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When i click between elements i get situation when nothng is selected. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way for this. You can't just `return false` in the unselecting event apparently.

Only thing I can think of is tap into the `selecting` and `selected` events yourself.
In the `selecting` event you could use `setTimeout` to add the 'ui-selected' class back to the ui element that is being unselected after couple of hundreds of ms. In the `selected` event you could `clearTimout` that to cancel.

That or cancel every click outside the selectable elements.

Comment: Thanks, i solve my problem in other way, that was one of option to get something which will need me. I have array to take care of state of clicked elements and in unselected event i set my array elements.

Answer (score 0):

[**Option** : *cancel*](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-cancel) may be helpful for your problem. I use as `cancel: ".ui-selected",`. This may be prevent from deselecting elements these are already selected.